# Messed up the .bashrc file

Tags: linux, centos, bashrc

So, I messed up the `.bashrc` file and now only the "cd" command works. How can I reset it to the default?. Be advised that "mv", "cp", "vi", etc do not works so I can't use them.

I searched for solutions but all of them includes using mv, cp or editing the file directly with vi or nano and as you know I can't use them.

I have work on it so formatting isn't an option.

PS: I'm using CentOS

Comment: Can you launch another shell ? Like zsh, csh, ksh perhaps ? Try the complete path to start them.

Comment: it sounds like you may have just messed up your `$PATH` variable; you could get more legs under you by doing: `PATH=/usr/bin`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can still login to the machine. If you are able to login as `root` user, I would login as root and update the normal users' `.bashrc`

I you can't login as another user, you should use your regular user. What to do then?

Unless something is very badly screwed, check that you are able to run `mv` and `cp` from their regular paths.

So instead of `mv .bashrc safe-bashrc` you can use

```
/bin/mv .bashrc safe-rc
```

Similar to `cp` ( `/bin/cp` ) and `vi` ( which can be either `/bin/vi` or `/usr/bin/vi`).

Then remove you `.bashrc`, fix it and return it.

Answer (score 1):

The default `~/.bashrc` can be found in `/etc/skel/`  the template for new home directories. Most likely you can still copy the `.bashrc` from there with with `/bin/cp`:

```
 /bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/att/.bashrc
```